# Regexmatch variable cell instead of ?2$

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got the following formula:

```
  IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     TO_TEXT(A1:A),
     "^(?i)[A-Z]+?2$"),
    "double",
    A1:A)))
```

Instead of only matching '2', I want it to match a specific cell. So that part should be something like: "^(?i)[A-Z]+? **D1** $"),

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simpler formula  for all your mentioned cases

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A3:A10&" ","\D+"&A1&" $|^"&A1&" $"), 
           "double",A3:A10))
```

[image]

***(do adjust ranges and locale according to your needs)***

*(Also: please do NOT keep altering your original question as well as double posting)*

Answer (score 0):

Replace 2 with "&D1&".

```
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     TO_TEXT(A1:A),
     "^(?i)[A-Z]+?"&D1&"$"),
    "double",
    A1:A)))
```